How to pre-load google ads with google publisher tag?
I have a next.js app that displays ads, how can I pre-load the ads on the server side so that when the page is fully loaded the ads are ready to be displayed. Is this possible? I understand that google publisher tag requires the app to be interactive before serving ads but is there a way I can pre-load them so that ads pre-loaded so that when the page is fully loaded the ads are immediately ready to be displayed? My current implementation is causing issues because the UI layout is changing to make room for the ads when they are loaded and UI elements are moving.
